# sql select using same table for join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Using mysql 4/5

I have 2 tables:

```
ROUTE
route_order (int)
zipcode

LOADS
load_id
pu_zipcode
do_zipcode
```

Goal:

select all rows from Loads where 
pu_zipcode and do_zipcode are in Route AND
where the route_order pu_zipcode < route_order do_zipcode

Comment: Have you got a associated foreign key between the two tables?

Comment: What field on both tables is common? You can join fields that aren't the same but it actually makes no sense doing so. Can you give a little more on details?

Comment: I'd attempted this using sub selects and IN clauses.. got nowhere and didn't want to confuse the question by adding horrible code

Comment: Doesn't matter, always post what you've tried.

Comment: Fair enough.. will next time.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking:

```
 SELECT L.*
 FROM Loads AS L
 JOIN Route AS R1
   ON R1.zipcode = L.PU_zipcode
 JOIN Route AS R2
   ON R2.zipcode = L.do_zipcode
 WHERE R1.ROUTE_ORDER < R2.ROUTE_ORDER
```

Comment: This worked.. first time needing multiple JOIN statements

Comment: is my WHERE clause correct or should it be R1.ROUTE_ORDER < R2.ROUTE_ORDER?

Comment: it should be R1.ROUTE_ORDER < R2.ROUTE_ORDER. I edited the code, maybe hasn't made it through peer review

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT l.load_id, l.pu_zipcode, l.do_zipcode 
FROM LOADS AS l, ROUTE AS r1, ROUTE AS r2
WHERE l.pu_zipcode=r1.zipcode
AND l.do_zipcode=r2.zipcode
AND r1.route_order<r2.route_order
```

Comment: your joins are unintelligible.